# Ubuntu 18.04 -Brightness dims when screen is not static

Tags: 18.04, screen, brightness

The screen seems to dim slightly when anything on it changes, whether that be a video playing, a window moving, or a cursor blinking.

This does not happen when something is playing in the background.

- Alienware 17 R2
- Ubuntu 18.04
- Gnome Shell version 3.28.2
- Nvidia GTX 980M
- Driver version 390
- Kernel Version is 4.15.0-30-generic

I have disabled The ambient light sensor and idle dim in dconf-editor. Advice would be appreciated.